# Geoserver: Update two related tables

Tags: geoserver

I'm newbie in the GIS field.
My project is a web mapping application that depends on OpenLayers, Geoserver, and PostGIS.
I have a spatial tables called "features-table", that has a one to many relationship to a non-spatial table called "tags-table", so that every feature has many tags. 
I want to update a feature with all its related tags; that means the two tables need to be updated. I'm not able to do that.

I've tried the following:

1- Created a view with the two tables, and used a WFS-T reuqest to update the attributes of that view, but found that geoserver treats views as read only.

2- Created a stored-procedure in PostGIS that updates the two tables, but when calling it from geoserver's "Configure new SQL view" it makes no effect.

Can you help me with how to do that?